# ngAnnotate Not Working on ES6 Classes with No Instance Methods

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, constructor-injection

I've been through the posts about improper dependency injection and resulting errors in minified code, and haven't been able to figure out why I'm getting it here.

**this produces `$injector:unpr` error when minified**

```
// Projects.projects = ['array', 'of', 'stuff']
import { Projects } from './projects';

export class PortfolioController
{
    /* @ngInject */
    constructor($state)
    {
        this.$state = $state;
        this.projects = new Projects().projects;
    }
}
```

**this minifies without error**

```
import { Projects } from './projects';

export class PortfolioController
{
    /* @ngInject */
    constructor($state)
    {
        this.$state = $state;
        this.projects = new Projects().projects;
        this.Init();
    }

    Init()
    {
        this.$state.name === 'portfolio' ? 
            console.log('PortfolioController instantiated') : 
            console.log('no-go');
    }
}
```

**the controller registration/state config in case that helps**

```
'use strict';

import { PortfolioController } from './portfolio.controller';

angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('PortfolioController', PortfolioController)
    .config(['$stateProvider', Config]);


function Config($stateProvider)
{
    // NOTE: adding this fixes the issue, but this does not seem like an ideal scenario
    PortfolioController.$inject = ['$state'];

    $stateProvider

    .state('portfolio',
    {
        url: '/portfolio',
        views: {
            'portfolio': {
                templateUrl: 'app/portfolio/views/portfolio.html',
                controller: PortfolioController,
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Ideas?

**update** - thought it might be helpful to include the module `setter`.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate'])
    .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$animateProvider', Config])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$state', Run]);

function Config($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $animateProvider)
{
    // basic ui.router config
}

function Run($rootScope, $state)
{
    // actions that occur when the app runs
}
```

Comment: Have you compared the unminified output to see if the `/* @ngInject */` is still in a reasonable place after Babel has processed the file?

Comment: I'm not sure what an unreasonable placing would be, but after the code has gone through Babel and Browserify, `/*@ngInject*/` is above this line: `exports.PortfolioController = function PortfolioController($state) {...};`

Comment: I discovered (using `ng-di-strict` in dev) that it works if I put `PortfolioController.$inject = ['$state'];` in my state config function. That doesn't seem ideal either, though . . .

Comment: It seems like this is probably a bug in `ngAnnotate`. Not sure what more can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has nothing to do with the annotations, since they should work properly even in the minified version of the code.

What I can tell you for sure, and this is also probably giving you the exact error message you get is, that you use `ui.router`, but you don't inject is as dependency in your module.

Be sure you have the library loaded in your browser and then inject it to the module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
    .controller('PortfolioController', PortfolioController)
    .config(['$stateProvider', Config])
```

Comment: I'm willing to entertain the notion that the problem is not with ngAnnotate, but it's not `ui.router` either, I don't think. That error is coming when the controller is instantiated. I'll update my question with the module setter, too, in case that is helpful.

Comment: Well I didn't actively work with ngAnnotate - but the `unkown provider` error certainly can come when you miss a dependency on module level.